# Connect Participant Scores(Column D) to their id Numbers(Column A) by sorting Columns B and C

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have 4 columns of data. I am trying to connect the Scores to the idNumbers.

Two sets of data. Column A and B are idNumber and Member names.

And Column C and D are Participants and their Scores.

The Participants are Members, but not all of the Members participated.

So, need a way to connect the Scores to the idNumbers by matching or sorting the Members and Participants.

I attached a small sample. The columns are actually 100's of members and participants long.

Ultimately, to create a weekly log of active Member's Scores.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: _Ultimately,create a weekly log of active Member's Scores._ Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post another question for that second part, and show your manually entered expected results.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0):

Put this `vlookup()` formula in row `1` of a free column:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(B1:B, C1:D, columns(C1:D), false) ) )`

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  That worked like a charm!

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)